# cannot clear textarea in ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

In my app, I have a chat area, where as the user focuses on the input textarea, the keyboard comes up, and once they hit the send button, the message send function is triggered and the keyboard slides down. But the textarea still contains the text. If I hit the send btn while the keyboard is not on screen, the text disappears properly.

my html for that part:

```
<ion-toolbar position="bottom">
        <ion-textarea placeholder="Type your message here" [(ngModel)]="chatfrm.chatMessage"></ion-textarea>
        <ion-buttons end>
            <button type="button" (click)="sendMessage(chatfrm.chatMessage);chatfrm.chatMessage='';" royal>Send<ion-icon name="send"></ion-icon></button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-toolbar>
```

And the js

```
sendMessage(msg){
    var tmpmsg = msg;//this.chatfrm.chatMessage;
    msg = "";
    this.chatfrm.chatMessage = "";
    console.log("reset");
}
```

Comment: Are you able to reproduce your error http://plnkr.co/edit/me3Uk0GKWVRhZWU0usad?p=preview ? and did you initialise chatfrm = [] in your constructor

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your function code with the zone.

import zone

```
import { Injectable,NgZone  } from '@angular/core';
```

add in constructor

```
constructor(public zone: NgZone) {

}
```

Function

```
 sendMessage(msg){
     this.zone.run(() => {
        var tmpmsg = msg;//this.chatfrm.chatMessage;
        msg = ""
        this.chatfrm.chatMessage = "";
        console.log("reset");
     })
    }
```